# Groupby a column containing duplicates but also preserving the duplicate information

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'id':['A','A','B','C','D'],'Name':['apple','apricot','banana','orange','citrus'], 'count':[2,3,6,5,12]})

   id     Name  count
 0  A    apple      2
 1  A  apricot      3
 2  B   banana      6
 3  C   orange      5
 4  D   citrus     12
```

I am trying to group the dataframe by the 'id' column, but also preserve the duplicated names as separate columns. Below is the expected output:

```
    id   sum(count)  id1      id2
 0  A    5           apple    apricot
 1  B    6           banana   na
 2  C    5           orange   na
 3  D    12          citrus   na
```

I tried grouping by the id column using the following statement but that removes the name column completely.

```
df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).sum()
```

I would appreciate any suggestions/ help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for this:

```
g = df.groupby('id')
# Generate the new columns of the pivoted dataframe
col = g.Name.cumcount()
# Sum of count grouped by id
sum_count = g['count'].sum()

(df.pivot_table(values='Name', index='id', columns = col, aggfunc='first')
   .add_prefix('id')
   .assign(sum_count = sum_count))

      id0     id1       sum_count
id                            
A    apple  apricot          5
B   banana      NaN          6
C   orange      NaN          5
D   citrus      NaN         12
```